# É possível fazer pequenas mudanças no meu pacote sem precisar mudar a versão no PyPi?

Tags: python, packages

Eu fiz um pacote no python e adicionei ele no [PyPi](https://pypi.org/). Agora, eu gostaria de atualizar apenas uma mensagem de erro.

Quando faço atualizações mais complexas, eu crio uma nova release no GitHub e atualizo a versão no meu arquivo `setup.py`.

No entanto, acho que seria um "overkill" criar uma nova release só para melhorar uma mensagem de erro. Ademais, ao que me parece esse não é o procedimento padrão já que vejo muitos pacotes com um pequeno número de releases. É possível fazer pequenas mudanças sem precisar mudar a versão do meu pacote no PyPi?

Gostaria de evitar algo que aconteceu no meu primeiro pacote no python (https://github.com/lucascr91/cartpy). Note que fiz 28 releases (!) porque criava uma nova release para cada mudança que fazia. Isso me parece desnecessário.

**O que tentei**

Bom, eu imaginei que eu poderia fazer uma pequena mudança e manter a mesma versão, então corrigir a mensagem de erro, fiz o commit para o GitHub e depois atualizei meu pacote usando:

```
pip install --upgrade meupacote
```

Não funcionou. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Acredito que o único modo é mudar  a versão sim. 
Algo relacionado (mas que não ajuda no seu caso específico) é quando você está testando algo específico do empacotamento. Nesse caso você pode usar https://test.pypi.org/ ao invés do PyPi regular. Ainda vai ter que mudar a versão a cada mudança, mas ao menos você está mudando apenas no servidor de teste e após fazer o que queria pode mudar a versão apenas uma vez e fazer upload para o PyPi regular.

Comment: Obrigado, @darcamo